# Adding fields dynamically to a layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

In my application, I want to add fields dynamically based on the selection. While there are 4 fixed spinner fields, the values of spinner are dependent on the selection of the first spinner field etc. The second spinner field has to be populated based on the first field and the third spinner field based on the second field and so on.

Based on the options selected in these 4 spinner fields, the layout will contain additional fields that are text fields or radio buttons etc.

Can someone suggest what is the best way to achieve this or refer to other examples for this?

Thanks

Comment: can you post what have you done till??

Comment: So far, I have only created the 4 spinner fields and able to populate the spinner field values based on selection using OnItemClickListener. I am not able to progress on how to add the new fields based on these selections.

Comment: do you want to inflate a custom  view inside a layout or to created fields dynamically? and please post the code  so that we can understand were you got stuck?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a View to a Layout similar to the below code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

TextView view = new TextView(mContext);
view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

relativeLayout.addView(view);
```

And then you need to add it to an existing ViewLayout:

```
LinearLayout originalLayout = findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
originalLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
```

This idea can be expanded on to add custom Views etc to your screen.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. While I understand that you are creating a new layout and the components dynamically and adding it to the already defined layout, I would like to know how to add this on selection of spinner object. I have a layout with four spinner objects and they are populated using OnItemClickListener. How do I add the custom views based on the selection of these spinner objects.

Comment: Are you looking to get notified of the selection event? Use spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener());